# todo list with js: new list text content, doesn't update while adding new item

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a to-do list with JavaScript. As you can see in the code, I created a list where the first `<li>` is the to-do text input. As far as the user inputs text, the `to-do()` function is called and  when presses the `Enter` I take the text input value and then create a new `<li>` element inside the `<ul>` list and put the text value inside a `<span>` as a new to-do list text. so everything works OK unless the text of the new to-do list won't be updated and is still the same as previous input text value.
So I shared this with Google Bard and it said that the problem is because the `todo_title` variable is local in the `todo()` function and after the function is finished, the variable no longer existed, so I declared it outside the function but it didn't work.
I also tried Chat GPT and it said that I was appending the new content to the existing `todo_list` without clearing the previous content. so I cleared it with `todo_list.textContent = ""`, but didn't work.
I also tried reading the same questions with to-do list projects in Stackoverflow but none of them was related to my problem.
I want to understand why this is happening.

```js
let todo_input = document.getElementById("text");
let todo_list = document.querySelector(".todo_list");
let index = 0;
let todo_title;

function todo(event) {
  let key = event.key;
  if (key == "Enter") {
    todo_title = todo_input.value;
    //let todo_title = value; // it was local before
    let todo_list_content = todo_list.innerHTML;
    index++;
    todo_list.innerHTML = todo_list_content + `  
            <li>
                <span class="text">${todo_title}</span>
                <span class="icons">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox${index}" id="checkbox${index}">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash" style="color: #ff0000;"></i>
                </span>
            </li>
        `
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 0);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.todo_list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 22%;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.todo_list li {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.todo_list li:not(:first-child) {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 99%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.todo_list input {
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: cursive;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 99%;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: lightgrey;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

.icons input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="todo_list">
      <li class="input">
        <input name="text" id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter your task" value="" onkeydown="todo(event)">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/14a956106f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Where is your code for handling the input box? The problem doesn't seem to be in the code you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with the assignment to `innerHTML` you recreate the `<input>` element, but this input element is not the one you still have in your variable `todo_input` -- that is still the "old" one that is no longer on the HTML page (not part of the DOM). Still you read from it with `todo_input.value`. Of course, that old input element hasn't changed by the user typing new text. It still has the original text, and that is why that same text gets repeated and the newly entered text is ignored.

There are many ways to avoid this from happening, but most solutions would avoid replacing the `input` element. You could for instance use `insertAdjacentHTML` to only **append** the new `li`. This way the `todo_input` is still the (only) text input box. Now you will want to clear that input box whenever this `li` element has been added, so the user doesn't have to remove that text themselves before typing in the next task:

```js
let todo_input = document.getElementById("text");
let todo_list = document.querySelector(".todo_list");
let index = 0;

function todo(event) {
    let key = event.key;
    if (key == "Enter") {
        let todo_title = todo_input.value;
        todo_input.value = ""; // clear so user can start from scratch
        index++;
        // Don't delete any existing HTML -- only append:
        todo_list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `  
            <li>
                <span class="text">${todo_title}</span>
                <span class="icons">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox${index}" id="checkbox${index}">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash" style="color: #ff0000;"></i>
                </span>
            </li>
        `);
    }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 0);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.todo_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 22%;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.todo_list li {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.todo_list li:not(:first-child) {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width: 99%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.todo_list input {
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: cursive;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    width: 99%;
}

input::placeholder {
    color: lightgrey;
}

.icons{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
.icons input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="todo_list">
            <li class="input">
                <input name="text" id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter your task" value="" onkeydown="todo(event)">
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/14a956106f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: as far as your explanation:" That is still the "old" one that is no longer on the HTML page"
then how does its value in "todo_input.value" still exist and doesn't disappear?

Comment: It is an object that exists in memory. It can exist without any relationship to the display. It can even be added to the HTML page again, and you would see its value again. But realise that the object is in memory, whether it is displayed or not.

Comment: that makes sense more. can you give me some sources and links about this for more study?

Comment: You could look on MDN on DOM methods, like `createElement`, `appendChild` and `removeElement`. The first creates the element in memory, but is not part of the HTML page yet. With the second you add it to the document hierarchy and so it is now part of the HTML page. With the third you remove that object from the page again, but it still is in memory. You could add it again with `appendChild`, ...etc.